# How to send a non standard http status code in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to send a non standard http status code (468) from my rest controller. This should be based on conditions. If all goes well, I will return **ResponseEntity.ok()**. I tried **ResponseEntity.status(468).build()**, but I am getting **No matching constant for [468]**.

I tried several ways to modify the response, but nothing works. Tried to modify the response from controller advice, tried with interceptors and also with filter. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: could you provide more information regarding the issue (spring version, more detailed example). At least in the spring boot `2.6` `ResponseEntity.status(468).build()` works without any error.

Comment: Hi! 1) use int instead of Integer. 2) send int as shown above status(int), without HttpStatus.valueOf()